# How to develop random Analysis Programme?

Tags: random

How to develop random Analysis Programme for selecting students for addmissions in 1st standard among 700 students distributing 24% to general, 11% to SC 5% to St,0.5% to PH?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Your percentages don't add up to 100. Are they meant to?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a spreadsheet program that has a random number generator.

1. Put your 700 student ID's in the first column.
2. In the second column, set it to: RAND().
3. Sort the 700 rows by the 2nd column.
4. Assign the first 24% of the students to general, next 11% to SC, etc.